# Python: removing columns with standard deviation less than 25th percentile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataframe with many columns (variables). My overall goal is to remove invariant columns defined as columns with a standard deviation smaller than the 25th percentile.

For added nuance, I would like this process to be robust to non-float or non-integer columns.

Here is as far as I can get:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
'a':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'b':[1,1,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'c':['Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes','No']
})

dummy_df = df.quantile([0.25], axis=0) <= df.std(axis=0)
```

Comment: `df.loc[:, df.quantile(0.25) < df.std()]` ?

Comment: This is a great answer to the question I posed, with one caveat: it fails on non-numeric columns. Is there a way to retain the non-numeric columns?

I have added a binary non-numeric variable to my toy example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can take Raf's solution and implement it on Numeric columns:

```
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
new_df = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics).loc[:, df.quantile(0.25) < df.std()]
df = pd.concat([new_df, df.select_dtypes(exclude=numerics)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This works great! But is there a way to keep the non-numeric columns. Imagine I had 3 million columns and ~30% of them were non-numeric.

Comment: I have edited the solution. I later concat back the non-numeric columns

Comment: Very close, but I get what you are trying to do.  Thank you so much.

This worked for me:                                                                    
    numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
    new_df = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics).loc[:, df.quantile(0.25) < df.std()]
    df1 = pd.merge(new_df, df.select_dtypes(exclude=numerics), left_index=True, right_index=True)